# Compile in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I have a little problem when I compile project in D5.

1. Open existing project.
2. Compile it (compile eg 13k lines).
3. Compile once again with no change in source. Now compiler has no changes so count of compiled lines should be smaller, but lines count is the same.

It's looks like compiler allways detect some changes in source files. Where is problem could it be problem with some parameters in .pas files?

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: Why? After first compile delphi generate dcu and should use it (with next compile) as long until the sources will not change or not? If no .dcu-s are for nothing.

Comment: I'm saying that my Delphi behaves fine. What is different about yours.

Comment: Could it be that the compiler is finding a set of out of date DCUs on its search path somewhere other than your DCU output folder?

Comment: Yeah, its good question. I think there is some problem with some attributes iin files. What is really importat for compiler when recognize file as changed? Sometimes I edit .pas unit in different editor, maybe it's problem. Editor make some changes in file attributes compiler, recognize it as difference but coudn't change it. It's possible?

Comment: @MartynA Interesting idea but when I replace some of .pas unit to after version (version edit only by delphi IDE) problem disappears. So i think it's wrong resolve.

Comment: From the IDE, did you do "compile" or "build"? Using an external editor shouldn't matter. Delphi is comparing the source date against that of the build products.

Comment: @lurker Compile, with I would not have any doubts. Are you sure? I have heard that IDE editor round time to 2sec.

Comment: Ok just wanted to be sure. If it rounds to two seconds and that were your issue, it should be easy to test and confirm.

Comment: you could delete all dcu files for this project and than check if they are created after a compile. If not than your working with wrong dcu path somehow

Comment: @GuidoG When i do that, dcu files have been restored. I think dcu path is good, swapping .pas files solves the problem. I wonder what is the metter with these files.

Comment: What do you mean by swapping.pas files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Delphi 5 not in its default `program files` directory?

Since Vista/Seven, you should better use another directory, due to UAC virtual folders. I usually create a `c:\progs` folder in which I install the various old Delphi versions I have to use.

Also check where the `dcu` files are located, both your `dcu` files and also the RTL's.

Comment: very good advise, but when the project itself is not in the `programs files` directory then this should not matter IMO ?

Comment: I made the same installation as you in "c:\programs".

Comment: Another thing that I noticed is the problem occurs after copying files from a remote repository..

Comment: You need to check where the `dcu` files are located, and ensure it is not in `Program Files`...